Finding a network such that two slight modifications of Edmond-Karp output different flows
Let $\mathcal{N} = (V, E, c)$ a network where $c$ is a function that maps edges to values in $\mathbb{R}^{+} \cup \{0\}$. Let $\Gamma^{+}(x) = \{y \in V : (x, y) \in E\}$ and $\Gamma^{-}(x) = \{y \in V : (y, x) \in E\}$.
Furthermore, assume $\mathcal{N}$ is such that $(x, y) \in E \iff (y, x) \in E$; this is, all edges are bidirectional.
I'm experimenting with the Edmonds-Karp algorithm, which (being famous) I will not explain in detail here. Suffice it to say, it is a combination of Ford-Fulkerson and BFS, where BFS is used to build augmenting paths.
Imagine that we modify BFS in two distinct ways:

$BFS_1$ : When finding the neighbors of $x$, it first searches in $\Gamma^+(x)$ and then in $\Gamma^{-}(x)$. I want to determine if there is some network satisfying the conditions above s.t.


$BFS_2$ : When finding the neighbors of $x$, it first searches in $\Gamma^-(x)$ and then in $\Gamma^{+}(x)$.

I want to determine if there is some network satisfying the conditions above s.t. running Edmonds-Karp with $BFS_1$ and with $BFS_2$ on it results in two different flows.
Naturally, the max-flows will be the same; but I'm interested in whether the flows themselves can differ. I have not find any literature on this idea, though it seems a pretty natural question, and have failed to tackle the issue by myself. Any ideas?
